# Best practices for grails index page

Tags: grails, indexing, model

What is the right way to populate the model for the index page in a grails app? There is no IndexController by default, is there some other mechanism for getting lists of this and that into the model?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I won't claim that this is the right way, but it is one way to start things off. It doesn't take much to have a controller be the default. Add a mapping to UrlMappings.groovy:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
      "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }
      "500"(view:'/error')
     "/"
        {
            controller = "quote"
        }
    }
}
```

Then add an index action to the now default controller:

```
class QuoteController {

    def index = {
        ...
    }
}
```

If what you want to load is already part of another action simply redirect:

```
def index = {
    redirect(action: random)
}
```

Or to really get some reuse going, put the logic in a service:

```
class QuoteController {

    def quoteService

    def index = {
        redirect(action: random)
    }

    def random = {
        def randomQuote = quoteService.getRandomQuote()
        [ quote : randomQuote ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the UrlMappings should probably have read `"/" {controller: "quote"}`.  It didn't work for me until I changed the "=" to a ":".

Comment: `static defaultAction = "random"` - instead of redirect from index action you can add defaultAction static field to the controller with desired action name as value.

Answer (score 21):

I couldn't get Ed T's example above to work. Perhaps Grails has changed since then?

After some experimentation and some rummaging on the net, I ended up with this in `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
    "/"(controller: 'home', action: 'index')
```

My HomeController looks like this:

```
class HomeController {

  def index = {
    def quotes = = latest(Quote.list(), 5)
    ["quotes": quotes, "totalQuotes": Quote.count()]
  }

}
```

And in `views/home`, I have an `index.gsp` file. That makes the `index.gsp` file in views unnecessary, so I removed it.

Comment: The important bit for me was (re)moving the /views/index.gsp. Until then it had worked for e.g. localhost:8080/ but not for a simple localhost:8080

Answer (score 4):

**The good answer:** If you need to populate a model for the index page, it's time to change from using a straight index.gsp to an index controller.

**The evil answer:** If you create a filter whose controller is '*', it'll get executed even for static pages.

Answer (score 0):

In grails 1.3.6 for just adding

`"/index.gsp"(uri:"/")`

to UrlMappings.groovy worked fine for me. It has the same effect as adding a new controller and mappings like described before.

Below is my complete UrlMappings.groovy:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')

        "/index.gsp"(uri:"/")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does redirection with uri work in UrlMappings? I tried it (for a slightly different usecase), and it didn't. Got an error that controller was null. I had to resort to redirecting from a controller.